# Autocomplete a textbox in c#

Tags: c#, textbox, autocomplete

I'm trying to autocomplete a textbox. I'm retrieving values from Access Database. Just one field from a data table. If anyone can help me.

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: Google is your friend. e.g.: autosuggest textbox asp.net.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource%28VS.80%29.aspx and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx

Comment: Why does the database matter on a UI question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection autoCompleteList = 
                                            new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
/* copy your datacolumn in to autoCompleteList iteratively here */
txtBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend; /* or just Suggest */
txtBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteList;
```

Comment: You forgot `txtBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/simplepopup.aspx) control in your application if you using c# application.