# How to add intellisense into my application

Tags: c#-4.0, vb6

i intend to build an application with a feature like auto complete text (e.g. Google search uses auto text ) i learnt it is been done with inensetellis (a .dll tool by microsoft). can anyone plz tell me how to include such feature in my application. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autocomplete a textbox in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452663/autocomplete-a-textbox-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you looking for whole text completion (single line text box with auto complete) or command completion (like the Visual Studio IDE) for completing text inline?

Answer (score -1):

The WinForms controls support auto completion with auto completion source objects. See the [`TextBox.AutoCompleteSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx) and associated properties.

Comment: hi deana, its a single single line text box with auto complete but would accept not just word but full sentence. 10x

Comment: Then it's normal auto complete, you just need to provide a source for it to auto complete to.

Comment: @Deanna what to do if want  intellisense which should be work on Notepad,Wordpad, MS office Word,etc i.e. anywhere there is textbox like input controls with my own custom Source of words

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar that will require modifying the program on question and is unrelated to win forms or this question.

Comment: @Deanna can you specify which language or what can be helpful to me in this case

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar no, I don't know. You're best of asking a new question that is relevant to your subject.